# Communication between Microblaze and RTL IP core

Tags: communication, ethernet, vivado, rtl, axi

I have done an ethernet project (Echo) (TCP/IP) using vivado block design and the board used is Artix A7 and MICROBLAZE PROCESSOR WITH AXI_INTERCONNECT. I was able to use AXI_GPIO connected to an led, and using Herclues interface, I was able to toggle the led by commands that i send and were previously defined in SDK.

Now to make it more complex, I have RTL ip cores written in verilog, and I need to send data to the rtl ip and receive data from it too.

what i did is that i used AXI_INTERCONNECT --- 2 input AXI_GPIO & 2 output AXI_GPIO ---- to my RTL CORE

However, for somereason, when i am sending data via Herclues, and reading it, its working perfect, but once i connect my rtl core to ports and those port are assigned to pins, and those pins connected to OSCLISCOPE to check, there is litrally no data being sent at all !!

I have been through something weird too, that when i connect the axi_GPIO to a normal port (led), i can not control it via ethernet (herclues), i need to right click on the axi_gpio, and make it external, then a master port is generated. only that port is working.

Could you please help me with that? is it possible to do what i am actually doing? or i need to make my rtl cores as axi custom cores?

?[image][image]